# Convert a dataframe column (coded in dictionary format) to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

In a pandas dataframe,

How do I convert a dataframe with a column coded in dictionary format

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{'name': 'aaa', 'clusterName': 'AAA'}, {'name': 'bbb', 'clusterName': 'BBB'}] |
| 2 | [{'name': 'ccc', 'clusterName': 'CCC'}, {'name': 'ddd', 'clusterName': 'DDD'}] |
| 3 | [{'name': 'ccc', 'clusterName': 'CCC'}] |

To this?

| id | name | clusterName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | AAA |
| 1 | bbb | BBB |
| 2 | ccc | CCC |
| 2 | ddd | DDD |
| 3 | ccc | CCC |

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
import ast
#if necessary
#df['data'] = df['data'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

df1 = df.explode('data').reset_index(drop=True)
df1 = df1.join(pd.json_normalize(df1.pop('data')))
print (df1)
   id name clusterName
0   1  aaa         AAA
1   1  bbb         BBB
2   2  ccc         CCC
3   2  ddd         DDD
4   3  ccc         CCC
```

Another solution:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([{**{'id':a}, **x} for a, b in zip(df['id'], df['data']) for x in b])
print (df1)
   id name clusterName
0   1  aaa         AAA
1   1  bbb         BBB
2   2  ccc         CCC
3   2  ddd         DDD
4   3  ccc         CCC
```

Comment: Your top solution worked for me (I needed to run apply(ast.literal_eval)). Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Rudimentary Approach:

```
data = [
[{'name': 'aaa', 'clusterName': 'AAA'}, {'name': 'bbb', 'clusterName': 'BBB'}],
[{'name': 'ccc', 'clusterName': 'CCC'}, {'name': 'ddd', 'clusterName': 'DDD'}],
[{'name': 'ccc', 'clusterName': 'CCC'}]
]

newArr = []
for lists in data:
    for dicts in lists:
        newArr.append(dicts)
        
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(newArr)
```

The df variable matches the output as the Answer above as well

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

data = [
[{'name': 'aaa', 'clusterName': 'AAA'}, {'name': 'bbb', 'clusterName': 'BBB'}],
[{'name': 'ccc', 'clusterName': 'CCC'}, {'name': 'ddd', 'clusterName': 'DDD'}],
[{'name': 'ccc', 'clusterName': 'CCC'}]
]

pd.DataFrame(itertools.chain(*data))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).